# Inverse Z transform of a left sided signal

Tags: z-transform

Please help me to find the impulse response $h(n)$ of a Transfer function $H(z) = \dfrac{1+\frac{1}{6}z^{-1}}{1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}}$ given $h(n)$ is left sided.

Comment: The solution for such a prblem has 3 steps: 1-)  perform long division of H(z).  2-) perform partial fraction expansion on the remaning fractional part. 3-) perform inverse Z-transform considering the left-sided inverses... Which step are you stuck in ?

Comment: I'd be happy if I get (2) Partial fraction expansion and (3) Inverse Z transform part

Comment: If $h(n)$ was right sided, the answer would be $h(n) = \left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^nu[n]+\dfrac{1}{6}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1}u[n-1]$... I think.. But I am confused how to arrive at the answer when $h(n)$ is left sided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the order of your numerator equals the denominator, first perform a long division to simplify, before performing partial fraction expansion:

$$ H(z) = \frac{ 1 + 1/6 z^{-1}}{1 - 0.25 z^{-1}} = -\frac{2}{3} + \frac{5/3}{1 - 0.25 z^{-1}} $$

(Note: long divison already simplified the expression that it does not require a further partial fraction expansion to be applied, hence skip step-2 now)

Now apply the inzerve Z-transform and note that for left sided inverse sequence wil be $-a^n u[-n-1]$ for a term like $1/(1-az^{-1})$.

Comment: Got the long division correct. Now on taking the inverse transform, $$h(n) = \dfrac{-2}{3}\delta (n)-\dfrac{5}{3}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^nu(-n-1)$$ \\ Is this correct?

Comment: yes it does seem so ;-)

Comment: Now that you got your solution right, can you figure out the answer without long division (just by breaking the initial ratio into two and taking inverse Z on both)? And if yes, can you verify that this answer is identical with the one you've already got? In other words, can you start from $$h[n] = (1/4)^n u[-n-1] - (1/4)^{n-1}u[-n]$$ and reach the same result? I think it's a good exercise. :)

Comment: @GKH good point! one should also be able to see the solution from other perspectives. Although its correct application should yield : $$h[n] = -(0.25)^n u[-n-1] - \frac{1}{6}(0.25)^{n-1} u[-n] $$

Comment: @Fat32, oops, my bad! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Fat32 and GKH. I got the answer right. But as GKH suggested, I started with $h[n] = (0.25)^n u[-n-1] - (0.25)^{n-1}u[-n]$ but got no idea hot to equate it to $h(n) = \dfrac{-2}{3}\delta (n)-\dfrac{5}{3}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^nu(-n-1)$. Pls help

Comment: @Shehin, no, Fat32 mentioned the correct impulse response to start with. Mine was wrong. You should start from $$h[n]=-(0.25)^n u[-n-1] - \frac{1}{6}(0.25)^{n-1} u[-n]$$

Comment: @Shehin You've got your answer. Would you mind accepting ?

Comment: @GKH Yes me too forgot that $\frac{1}{6}$ there. But still I could not equate the two $h(n)$ obtained thru either cases

Comment: @Shehin, you should play around with the second term. Try to extract a delta function at $n=0$ out of it and see what is left.

Comment: @GKH Thank you I got it.